# Как подключить sfml к проекту cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, clion, git-submodule

Я использую Clion и пытаюсь подключить sfml с помощью add_subdirectory. Проект компилируется, но когда я его запускаю из IDE, возвращается код -1073741515, а когда вручную - появляется сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.1 FATAL_ERROR)
set(PROJECT_NAME Roguelike)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
        src/scenes/lobby.cpp src/scenes/lobby.h src/game.cpp src/game.h src/main.cpp src/state.h src/state.cpp
        )

add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/files/ $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>)

add_subdirectory(lib/SFML)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE lib/SFML/include)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE sfml-window sfml-audio sfml-system sfml-network sfml-graphics)
```

Cтруктура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ОС Windows 10, Компилятор MinGW

Comment: Если оно собирается, то значит подключено все верно. Однако надо не забывать потом вручную копировать все зависимости в папку с exe

Comment: У меня теперь в clion запускается, а вручную нет

Comment: Указывайте что теперь за ошибка... Телепаты в отпуске.

Comment: См. примеры подключения тут https://github.com/SFML/SFML/blob/master/cmake/SFMLConfig.cmake.in.

Comment: Точка входа в процедуру _ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv не найдена в библиотеке DLL C:\projects\cpp\cmake\sfml_roguelike\build\Roguelike.exe

Comment: Точка входа в процедуру _ZSt28__throw_bad_array_new_lengthv не найдена в библиотеке DLL C:\projects\cpp\cmake\sfml_roguelike\build\sfml-system-d-3.dll

Comment: еще раз - надо не забывать потом вручную копировать все зависимости в папку с exe

Comment: Я заменил компилятор на visual c++ и всё заработало